# Aggregate and subtraction

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I have following datasets called plots.

```
Id Genus value
1   null  1
2   QUST  3
3   SMBO2  4
.
.
200  SYLAR 7
```

I want to aggregate the value by subtracting 200 from the null data in every 200 datasets. Is there a way to do it? I did this way but I am missing the subtraction part here.

```
Data<- aggregate(plots, by = list(id, value), FUN = SUM)
```

Comment: I've read this 4 times and still have no idea what you mean. Why would you want to perform a mathematical operation on null data? It doesn't make sense. To better your chances of receiving help, restructure your question including a reproducible data set.

Comment: What I want to do is to find how many are the actual species are in 200 datasets? If you subtract null from the datasets, you get the actual number. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the null values before aggregating the data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I have understood you comments correctly, you want to aggregate your data and remove any incomplete cases(?)

This can be achieved using function `complete.cases(x)` where `x` is a sequence of vectors, matrices and data frames. The return is a logical vector specifying which observations/rows have no missing values across the entire sequence.

To adopt this code into your example:

```
Data <- aggregate(plots[complete.cases(plots)], by = list(id, value), FUN = SUM)
```

Please see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html) for more information and examples on using `complete.cases()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond. I simply used this code and it worked. Thanks a lot.